# Get proper URLs using Get-SPSite

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to get a list of site collection URLs (SP 2010):

```
"http://is-sp2010portal:1234" | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL > "C:\Desktop\New folder\1.txt"
```

It works fine for short URLs, but there is problem with long - they are not returning properly (I got them shortened with "..."):

```
http://is-sp2010portal:1234/sites/English Courses an...   
http://is-sp2010portal:1234/sites/English Levels Ada...
```

Is it possible to fix it?
If not - will be gratefull for advising an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"http://is-sp2010portal:1234" | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Desktop\New folder\1.txt"
```

it should make sure that the output is not truncated

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer :)